# Planeswalker siblings series

Tags: story-identification, novel

About seven years ago I flipped through a book, perhaps part of a trilogy, about a family consisting of a dozen siblings, Princes in Amber style. What I dimly remember is that:

- The siblings distrust/compete with each other,
- They can hop between planes somehow and rule the beings that inhabit those planes as they consider themselves superior beings and use their powers to subjugate or control other species,
- The protagonist is one of the siblings, he was in love with a 'lesser being' a woman with long dark hair? and thanks to her he became more human and emphatic
- the siblings got trapped on a plane and they cooperated (sort of) to escape and the youngest one (Jonathan?)  was literally turned into a giant whiny toad and everyone was hating on him except the protagonist,
- The siblings could hop between planes but not travel through space, as they lived in a simulated reality presumably created by beings even more superior.

And that's all I remember beside thinking that the author must have really liked Zelazny's books...

Comment: Like literally turned into a "whinny toad"? Or is this a slang term I'm unfamiliar with, saying that he got really whiny?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots no, he literally turned into a giant toad triggering a magic trap and whined a lot about it